# Understanding syntax in do file

Tags: stata

I am pretty new to Stata and just started learning.
I have a .do file with code that I try to understand. I am unsure what the following block of code is doing exactly.

```
set obs 150
generate x = 5+int((10-5+1)*runiform())

count
local bigN = r(N)

generate y = x / `bigN'
```

Am I correct in assuming that

- After the creation of 150 observations, a variable `x` is created that contains a random number for each of the 150 observations.
- Then a `local` is used to store the number of observations (150) in the variable bigN as a single number.
- Finally a new variable `y` is created that has each value of `x` divided by the number of observations stored in `bigN` (meaning the value of `y` for the first observation is the first value of `x` divided by 150 and so on).

Have I understood this correctly? If so, why is  `local` used and not `generate`? It appears that `local` is only working when using the .do file completely.

Comment: You could `generate bigN = r(N)` but there is no point in this context in holding the same constant in every observation. Other way round, unless the local `bigN` will be used later in this code there is no good reason not just to divide by `r(N)` directly: the `local` is then superfluous. Yet further, the `count` is harmless but pointless too, as the number of observations is known as 150 and if you want more generality it is directly accessible as `_N`. So, this is not your do-file but on this sample it is likely to have all sorts of ways of getting from A to B via C or G.

Comment: `runiformint(5, 10)` is a direct way to get the random numbers. Possibly this code was written before `runiformint()` was added to Stata. But even so asking Stata to calculate 10 - 5 + 1 again and again would seem to be something that a programmer could do. Someone is thinking of a general formula based on a + int(b - a + 1) but if you are wiring in specific code it might as well be simplified.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is essentially what it does.

A local is not a regular Stata variable. It is a temporary object that is only available within one execution of code. Assume you run the two following lines of code.

```
local i = 5
disp `i'
```

When you run them jointly, it prints:

```
. local i = 5

. disp `i'
5
```

Running them separately prints:

```
. local i = 5
.
. disp `i'
```

Running the two lines separately does not print the 5 because Stata only saves locals within one execution. In contrast to locals, globals are accessible across separate executions of code.

Comment: Thank you so much! So dividing by the local is the same as writing generate y = x / 150 ?

Comment: Yes, in this case it is the same.